# Upbge Node Logic Editor "Run python code"

Tags: python, blender

I don't understand why this **Node Logic Editor  "Run python code"** doesn't want to execute that? [image]

```
Import bge 
print("start")
Animations = []

Animations = bge.logic.globalDict
if len(Animations) == 0:
    print("Warnning | Animations List is 0")
    Animations = ["Default0", "Default1", "Default2"]
    print(Animations)
    


def Hallo():
    print("hallo")
    
print("end")
```

When I run the same script in the **Logic Bricks Editor**, it works perfectly!

If I leave it out, **"Run python code"** it works as usual.